Can I substitute $\cos^{(k)}(0)+i\sin^{(k)}(0)$ for $i^k$ in a series with index k?
I was trying to come up with a derivation of Euler's Formula inspired by a section in Thomas' Calculus, and I am using the following equation in this derivation
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\cos^{(k)}(0)+i\sin^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\theta^k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i^k}{k!}\theta^k\right)$$
where $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$
The reason I thought that the equation above would hold true is the following equality I found while I was trying to develop the derivation
$$\cos^{(k)}(0)+i\sin^{(k)}(0)=i^k$$
To the best of my ability, I cannot see why these equations would not hold, but I am unsure and would love to have someone help me understand if I have made a mistake or have missed some subtlety that means that one or both of these two equations does not hold?
Thank you very much for your kind help!

You can check that equality explicitly only for 4 values of $k$ because "derivate period" of both $\sin$ and $\cos$ equals 4.

Thank you @EgorIvanov! I checked that in Maple and it seems to me to be correct. So you would agree that the equality holds?

Yeah, they are true

Thank you very much for your help @EgorIvanov!
